# Calculate the SD of winning a lottery

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ People participate in lottery.

The probability function of $X$ Is $P\{X=i\} = ci^2, i=1,2,...,20$

Exactly one of the participates wins, each participant has the same probability of winning.

Someone participate the lottery each day, what is the SD of the number of times he will participate lottery until his first win?

---

I calculated $c$ Using $\sum_{i=1}^{20}P\{X=i\} = 1 \Rightarrow c = \frac{1}{2870}$.

Also, the probability to win a single lottery i think is $1/i$.

To calculate SD of first time winning a lottery, i thought to use geometric distribution, and by the formula for $SD$ For that distribution:

$$
SD = \sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p^2}}, p = 1/i \Rightarrow SD = \sqrt{i-1}
$$

But all the options for answer are finite values, independent of a varible, namely, not my answer.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probability to win a lottery on a given day is $p=P(\text{win})=\sum_{i=1}^{20}P(\text{win}\wedge i\text{ people participate})\\=\sum_{i=1}^{20}P(\text{win}\mid i\text{ people participate})P(i\text{ people participate})\\=\sum_{i=1}^{20}\frac1i\times ci^2=3/41$